Кросскомпиляци ZeroMQ
Пытаюсь скомпилировать ZeroMQ с помощью MinGW  из Linux (Ubuntu 22.04) под Windows и получаю ошибку от отсутствии condition_variable_any в пространстве имен std (error: 'condition_variable_any' in namespace 'std' does not name a type). Конфигурировал так - ./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 , собираю с помощью make. Такое ощущение что как то неправильно влкючился заголовочный файл #include <condition_variable>, потому что компилятор предлагает его включить:
src/condition_variable.hpp:71:1: note: 'std::condition_variable_any' is defined in header '<condition_variable>'; did you forget to '#include <condition_variable>'?
   70 | #include <condition_variable>
  +++ |+#include <condition_variable>
   71 |

Что это за ошибка и как это решать? 

Покажите ошибку целиком.

А на скриншоте практически и есть вся ошибка (дальше еще пару раз ругается на не объявленную переменную _cv), больше ошибок нет

"А на скриншоте практически и есть вся ошибка" - не делайте так. А в вопросе явно нехватает подробностей до mcve

Я думаю какая-то кривая версия MinGW попалась, в моей этот класс есть. Когда устанавливаете, там вроде как несколько пакетов на выбор, с разными thread model, попробуйте другой.

Еще могу предложить свой https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2, там zeromq для mingw есть в уже скомпилированном виде, как пакет.
